# How would I push slash commands to all the guilds the bot currently is in?

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

I know there is TONS of answers on here for this question but none fit the command handler I'm using.
Could anyone tell me how I would register my slash commands to ALL guilds my bot is in?
Click [here](https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/oyupopiquc.typescript) for the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code being

```js
 client.on('ready', async () => {
        const TestGuild = await client.guilds.cache.get('928297578691432480');
        TestGuild.commands.set(commandsArray)
    });
```

You are accessing the [`GuildApplicationCommandManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildApplicationCommandManager), you need to access the [`ApplicationCommandManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ApplicationCommandManager) directly available to your `Client` at  [`ClientApplication#commands`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ClientApplication?scrollTo=commands) therefore a simple change would look something like so:

```js
client.application.commands.set(commandsArray)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  If you still face issues let me know by commenting or editing your question!

Comment: Hey, would you know how to also make the permissions system serverwide, because it only works on the test server. The code is at https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/dokaciyoju.typescript on line 5 (I have already fixed line 16)

Comment: Again you would do `client.application.commands.permissions.set([permarray])`